# Filling empty vector inside while loop - R

Tags: r, vector, cluster-analysis

can somebody help me please with my cluster analysis?

I try to put values in an empty vector inside a while loop and are not able to manage it.

I am searching for the minimum value of my distance matrix and then put these values in every step of the while loop into a vector.

You can find the part of the code at variable "meltLevel" in the middle of the code.

Thanks in advance.

```
standardMatrix <- matrix (runif(25, max = 50, min = 1), nrow = 5, ncol = 5)
print(standardMatrix)
dist <- function(x1, x2) sqrt(sum((x1 - x2)^2))
distanceMatrix <- matrix(, nrow=5, ncol=5)
for (x in 1:4) {
    for (y in (x+1):5) {
    vector1 <- standardMatrix[x,];
        vector2 <- standardMatrix[y,];
    distanceMatrix[x,y] <- dist(vector1, vector2);
               }
        }
distanceMatrix <- t(distanceMatrix)
print(distanceMatrix)
while(dim(distanceMatrix)[1] > 2) {
distanceMatrix <- rbind(distanceMatrix, NA)
distanceMatrix <- cbind(distanceMatrix, NA)
newInd <- dim(distanceMatrix)[1]
endInd <- dim(distanceMatrix)[1] - 1
meltLevel <- numeric(0)
meltLevel <- c(meltLevel, min(distanceMatrix, na.rm = TRUE))
print(meltLevel)
minVal <- which(distanceMatrix == min(distanceMatrix, na.rm=TRUE), arr.ind=TRUE)
print(minVal)
   endInd = dim(distanceMatrix)[1]-1
    for(col in 1:endInd){
      if(!(col == minVal[1] || col == minVal[2])) {
        v <- c(distanceMatrix[minVal[1],col],distanceMatrix[col,minVal[1]],distanceMatrix[col,minVal[2]],distanceMatrix[minVal[2],col])
        minV <- min(v, na.rm=TRUE)
        distanceMatrix[newInd,col] = minV  
      }
    }
maxMinVal <- max(minVal)
minMinVal <- min(minVal)
distanceMatrix <- distanceMatrix[-maxMinVal,]
distanceMatrix <- distanceMatrix[-minMinVal,]
distanceMatrix <- distanceMatrix[, -maxMinVal]
distanceMatrix <- distanceMatrix[, -minMinVal]
print(distanceMatrix)

}

print(meltLevel)
```

Comment: Hi Max, on line 7, there is no object `m1`. If you want debugging assistance, it's important to provide all objects necessary to run your code.

Comment: Hi Ian, thank you I changed this.